# Request.Form - Getting null responses

Tags: asp-classic

this a really old site we manage, i'm not too familiar with asp.classic so please bear with me. If you need anything specifically let me know.

I have a form for creating a news article. It'll post just fine according to F12 networking tab. Image attached below. You can see the values we want, ie, headline, article date, etc. However, instead of using those, it's as if the entire form is null / empty. It'll use a seemingly default date of 1899-12-30 00:00:00 for every date and then blank for everything else I try to set.

[image]

If I replace the request.form lines with hard-coded answers it'll work fine.

So I have to conclude i've messed up somewhere and i'm not reading it correctly. It's as if i'm requesting the wrong form, so I have a bad feeling this is basic as hell and i'm just clueless.

Form:

```html
   <form name="frm_edit" id="frm_edit" action="scr/scr_news_edit.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return check_form();">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
    <td width="100"></td><td width="400" align="right"><p><i><%= dat_last_edited %></i></p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Title</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="str_headline" id="str_headline" type="text" value="<%= str_headline  %>" style="width:100%;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Article Date</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><% call date_selector(dat_article_date,"dat_article_date",10,5) %></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Expiry Date</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><% call date_selector(dat_expiry,"dat_expiry",10,5) %></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Article</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea name="str_article" id="str_article" rows="15" style="width:100%;"><%= str_article %></textarea></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
    <td><p>Image 1</p></td>
    <td><% if str_image1<>"" then %>
      <img src="../sitepix/news/<%= str_image1 %>">
      <input name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" type="button" value="Delete" onClick="self.location.href='news_edit.asp?pageref=<%= int_news_id %>&fld=str_image1';">
      <input name="str_image1" id="str_image1"style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
      <% else %>
      <input name="str_image1" id="str_image1"style="width:100%;" type="file">
      <% end if %></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Image 1 Alt Text</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="str_alt1" id="str_alt1" type="text" value="<%= str_alt1  %>" style="width:100%;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><p>Image 2</p></td><td><% if str_image2<>"" then %>
      <img src="../sitepix/news/<%= str_image2 %>">
      <input name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" type="button" value="Delete" onClick="self.location.href='news_edit.asp?pageref=<%= int_news_id %>&fld=str_image2';">
      <input name="str_image2" id="str_image2"style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
      <% else %>
      <input name="str_image2" id="str_image2"style="width:100%;" type="file">
      <% end if %></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Image 2 Alt Text</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="str_alt2" id="str_alt2" type="text" value="<%= str_alt2  %>" style="width:100%;"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
    <td width="100"><p>Active?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="bln_active" id="bln_active" type="checkbox" value="true" <% if bln_active then : response.write(" checked") : end if %>></p></td><td width="400" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2">
    <input name="btn_save" id="btn_save" class="button" type="submit" value="Save">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input name="btn_cancel" id="btn_cancel" class="button" type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="javascript:self.location.href='news_list.asp';">
    </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="int_news_id" id="int_news_id" type="hidden" value="<%= int_news_id %>">
    <input name="action" id="action" type="hidden" value="<%= str_action %>">
    <input name="bln_sent" id="bln_sent" type="hidden" value="<%= bln_sent %>">
   </form>
```

Editing / Action Page:

```
int_news_id=request.Form("int_news_id")

dim str_action, int_news_id, dat_created, str_headline, str_short_description, str_article, dat_article_date, bln_active, bln_public, dat_last_edited
dim str_link,str_editor,str_masterimage1,str_image1,str_masterimage2,str_image2,str_alt1, str_alt2,str_file,str_pdf1,str_pdf_text1,str_pdf2,str_pdf_text2,str_pdf3,str_pdf_text3,dat_expiry,bln_staff,bln_broadcast,str_image3,str_image4,str_masterimage3,str_masterimage4,str_alt3,str_alt4
dim str_sql,str_redirect,bln_sent,str_news_sql,rs_news

str_action = request.Form("str_action")

if str_action = "edit" then
    str_news_sql = "SELECT tbl_news.* FROM tbl_news WHERE int_news_id = " & int_news_id & ";"
    else
    str_news_sql = "SELECT tbl_news.* FROM tbl_news LIMIT 0,1;"
end if

set rs_news = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs_news.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    rs_news.open str_news_sql, str_connection, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic '(CursorType,LockType)

if str_action <> "edit" then
    rs_news.addnew
end if

if not rs_news.eof then
    'All this crap does not work, request.Form is null, not sure why when it's posting correctly'
    rs_news("str_headline")=fnc_tidy_string_ado(request.Form("str_headline"))
    rs_news("dat_article_date")=formatdatetime(request.Form("dat_article_date"),1)
    rs_news("dat_expiry")=formatdatetime(request.Form("dat_expiry"),1)
    rs_news("str_short_description")=fnc_tidy_string_ado(request.Form("str_short_description"))
    rs_news("str_article")=fnc_tidy_string_ado(request.Form("str_article"))

    rs_news("dat_last_edited")=now()
    rs_news("str_alt1")=request.Form("str_alt1")
    rs_news("str_alt2")=request.Form("str_alt2")
    rs_news("str_alt3")=request.Form("str_alt3")
    rs_news("str_alt4")=request.Form("str_alt4")
    if request.Form("bln_active")="true" then : rs_news("bln_active")=-1 : else : rs_news("bln_active")=0 end if
    if request.Form("bln_public")="true" then : rs_news("bln_public")=-1 : else : rs_news("bln_public")=0 end if
    if request.Form("bln_staff")="true" then : rs_news("bln_staff")=-1 : else : rs_news("bln_staff")=0 end if
    rs_news("str_pdf_text1")=request.Form("str_pdf_text1")

    'This stuff works fine'
    rs_news("str_editor")=session("str_username")
    int_news_id = rs_news("int_news_id")
    rs_news.update
    rs_news("str_link")="news.asp?pageref="&rs_news("int_news_id")
    rs_news.update
end if

rs_news.close : set rs_news = nothing
response.Buffer=false
'response.Write(request.form("str_action"))
response.redirect "../news_list.asp?action=new"
```

It's worth noting, and I don't know if this is because of how old this site is, that break-points don't work at all in my solution. Including Break All. It's the reason why i'm resorting to F12 network for the post params.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is returned as binary in Classic ASP and can only be accessed as raw bytes using `Request.BinaryRead()`. The `Request.Form` collection only applies to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form data *(which is why it appears empty)*.

Comment: @Lankymart You're a gem. That's answered it perfectly, thank you very much. I didn't want to touch the form itself since it appeared to be working, but removing enctype="multipart/form-data" instantly solved my problem. 

Previously, we were using aspSmartUpload and I believe that perhaps that might have needed the binary response. Since this is no longer the case, it's no longer needed. 

Do you want to submit this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's already covered by the duplicate @Ryan so I won't be leaving an answer, but glad I could help.